# Reorder DIvs on small screens

Tags: jquery, css

I have a markup like this:

```
  <div class="white img"></div>
  <div class="black img"></div>
  <div class="black img"></div>
  <div class="white img"></div>
```

which is styled like a chessboard with following css:

```
@media (min-width:500px){.img{ 
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  height:50px;}}

@media (max-width:499px){.img{ 
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  float:none!important;
  }}

.white{  background-color:#fff;float:left}
.black{  background-color:#000;float:left}
```

On smaller screens the divs should be placed under each other alternately black and white. Find a working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bk0arf02/2/

I **cannot use css flexbox with order** here, **nor a nth selector with background colors**. What´s the best way to reorder divs to:

```
  <div class="white img"></div>
  <div class="black img"></div>
  <div class="white img"></div>
  <div class="black img"></div>
```

That it looks like:

[image]

Prefered by css, if not by use of jquery?

Comment: Is it only the color pattern or will they contain any content?

Comment: Are your divs always going to start and end with white on large screens, or do you have a variable size of the checkboard (i.e. unknown number of divs)?

Comment: *"I can't use flexbox"* ... why not?

Comment: @all: The output comes from a cms and I have limited access to the view means I need to stay with floats. the order is either starting with black or white with changing amount of "cells". what are divs here are in real png´s with either black or white background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved with using static values `position` and 'top'. But you can use jQuery for getting height of each `div` height assign this height as top for other `div's`.

You have 4 div's in these case, consider it has A, B, C, D respectively. Then If you want order like this C,B,D,A then assign C - top 0, B - top ( height of C ), D - top ( height of B, C ) and A - top : ( height of C, B,D). For all div's position should be `absolute`.

Here is the example with static values
[Reorder Divs](https://jsfiddle.net/bk0arf02/3/)